# Dataframe not filtering correctly when choosing a specific value (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

my `df` looks something like this:

| URN | col1 | col2 | col3 | TEMPPNUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100279 | 24.0 | 75.8 | 0.1 | 99.9 |
| 100055 | 52.2 | 47.8 | 0.0 | 100.0 |
| 107782 | 12.3 | 86.2 | 1.5 | 100.0 |
| 112956 | 12.3 | 86.2 | 1.5 | 100.0 |
| 139957 | 19.9 | 79.9 | 0.2 | 100.0 |

The `TEMPPNUM` column is created like this:

`df['TEMPPNUM'] = ((df['col1'] + df['col2'] + df['col3']))`

I am wanting to filter out all the rows of which the `TEMPPNUM` column does not equal 100.

`df = df.loc[(df['TEMPPNUM'] == 100)]`

However when I do this, more values are filtered out than what I am expecting. Is there a reason why? (My dataframe is much larger than the example).

It does filter out all values not equal to 100, but also quite a few rows where `TEMPPNUM` does equal 100.

Comment: Can you show us a working sample where rows = `100` have also been filtered? one reason could be, that a few values with `100` could be `object` and few `int/float`. So the `str` values are filtered out.

Comment: @MayankPorwal has a point there. If your data is inconsistent, you may get these unexpected results using that approach. Try using the `astype` when comparing - `df['TEMPPNUM'].astype(int) == 100`

Comment: This was one of my thoughts but I am still finding cells being removed that are not, I have tried with your suggested method as well, still to no avail. I can still see multiple rows being filtered out where the `['TEMPPNUM']` equals 100. I have used `df['TEMPPNUM'] = pd.to_numeric(df['TEMPPNUM'])` to make sure the row uses the correct type

Comment: I think we will need some sample data from the ones that are failing. Show is some samples where 100 is appearing like this: `df.head(5)`, `df.info()` where DF represents the 'filtered' table. Hope that makes sense

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/JHtSr0S.png I have screenshotted what I am seeing.

You can see straight away the URN: 100049 has been removed when it should not have been

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/JHtTqTS.png : and just for reference, this is the `df.info()` being updated as it was not on the original screenshot

Comment: @DanailPetrov any ideas as to why this happens? I have just changed the `.astype(float)' to .astype(int) and strangely enough it worked better, I have an excel sheet I am comparing too, I was missing 200+ values, now I am only missing 5, but I don't understand why this works better when the values are floats not integers

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it

```
>>> df.query('TEMPPNUM != 100')
```

Another way would be with 'mask'

```
>>> df[df.TEMPPNUM!=100]
```

Both should produce this output

```
      URN  col1  col2  col3  TEMPPNUM
0  100279  24.0  75.8   0.1      99.9
```

EDIT:

If your TEMPPNUM is NOT float/int, then you'd can either convert it to such or simply do that

```
>>> df.query('TEMPPNUM != 100')

      URN  col1  col2  col3 TEMPPNUM
0  100279  24.0  75.8   0.1     99.9
5  123321  91.0  99.0   0.5      100

>>> mask=df['TEMPPNUM'].astype(int) == 100

>>> df[~mask]

      URN  col1  col2  col3 TEMPPNUM
0  100279  24.0  75.8   0.1     99.9
```

Comment: I don't think this is what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the float comparison, which is not limited to the Pandas DataFrame. It is a general issue in Python (and probably other languages), where they are difficult to compare directly.
This explains why you'd have less issues when using integers.

The precision you see on the screen ("100.0") is not how it is stored, that is much more finegrained. And apparently not always the same due to rounding and precision.

For example/solution see a related question like [Comparing floats in a pandas column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626443/comparing-floats-in-a-pandas-column)

The solution is generally to compare if they are within some small distance of eachother instead of actually equal, e.g. via numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np    
>>> np.isclose(df['TEMPNUM'], 100.0)
    array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True])
>>> df[np.isclose(df['TEMPNUM'], 100.0)]
      URN  col1  col2  col3  TEMPNUM
1  100055  52.2  47.8   0.0    100.0
2  107782  12.3  86.2   1.5    100.0
3  112956  12.3  86.2   1.5    100.0
4  139957  19.9  79.9   0.2    100.0
```