# Why pandas eq() function not returning expected output

Tags: python, pandas

I want to take difference of each column data and see if it is equal to 0.6. I am using pandas (v2.0.2) read_csv to try to accomplish this.

main.py:

```py
import pandas as pd

file = "C:/Users/Documents/proj/data.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(file)

out = df["colA"].diff().eq(0.6)
print(out)
```

The output I get is:

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
```

The expected output should be:

```
0    False
1    True
2    True
3    True
```

data.csv contains:

```
colA
1.2
1.8
2.4
3
```

I don't understand why this is not working - Any suggestion is much appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) look at the `abs(1.2-1.8)`, which does not equal `.6`

Comment: Try using `isclose()` instead of `eq()`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626443/comparing-floats-in-a-pandas-column